# Updating Mysql table from CSV file

Tags: php, mysql

Hi Im trying to update a table testprod in my MYSQL db from a csv file. (I found the code on here and have updated it to my needs, well nearly :))

It updates but the decimal value is truncated and it loses any info after the (.) eg 400.25 is cut down to 400

here is an sample of the csv file

```
'Product_ID','Model','HighPic','ManuId','Model_Name','categories_id','categories_image','parent_id','sort_order','categories_name','categories_description','categories_keywords','Name','Image','Price','Supplier','Weight','Stock','datetime'
2055332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,800.4,,,'1',
3916211,,,,,,,,,,,,,,444,,,'15',
12073922,,,,,,,,,,,,,,737.6215,,,'0',
4593772,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2822.4,,,'4',
1684786,,,,,,,,,,,,,,4333.2,,,'1',
```

and here is the php code.

```
<?php

// set local variables
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","db","password") or die('Could    not connect: ' . mysql_error());
$handle = fopen("dailyupdates.csv", "r");

// connect to mysql and select database or exit 
mysql_select_db("rapido_creloaded", $connect);

// loop content of csv file, using comma as delimiter
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
$Product_ID = $data[0];
$price =  $data[14];
$stock = $data[17];



$query = 'SELECT Product_ID FROM testprod';
if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
continue;
} 

if ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

// entry exists update
$query = "UPDATE testprod SET price ='$price' , stock = '$stock'
WHERE Product_ID = '$Product_ID'";


mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_affected_rows() <= 0) {

// no rows where affected by update query
}
} else {
// entry doesn't exist continue or insert...
}

mysql_free_result($result);
}

fclose($handle);
mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

Comment: what is the datatype of that column?

Comment: datatype might be int for that column..check db..

Comment: the datatype is set to DECIMAL on the DB

Comment: `DECIMAL(20,2)`? And NO, do not use DOUBLE (inexact)

Comment: @Yogesh SutharChanged the DECIMAL to DOUBLE but the same happens.

Comment: @JoopEggen it was DECIAML (11,2) shall i try (20,2)

Comment: @JohnSpencer set its decimal point length also. Check my answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen my mistake it was DECIMAL(11,0) changed and working, thank you very much.,

Comment: @YogeshSuthar thanks it was my fault I only had it set to 11,0 and not 11,2, thanks for your input.

Comment: Is there a way to adapt this so you can see if product exists ? e.g. there was a match for the select?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SET its datatype to `DECIMAL(20,5)` OR `DOUBLE(20,5)`

**Edit**

Use this query

```
$query = "UPDATE testprod SET price ='$price' , stock = $stock
WHERE Product_ID = '$Product_ID'";
```

Comment: One more question please, (I have updated to the code above) to change the stock as well ( I didnt want to ask to many things in one go ). but the stock in the csv is enclosed with '' and this doesn't copy over at all. any pointers.  the data type for that column is INT  Thanks   John.

Comment: Once again thank you very much, I have been playing around with this for ages this morning always something so little with code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are on a mac but I use SequelPro.  Check them out at http://www.sequelpro.com/.  There are a few SQL management tools out there but for ease of use and cost, these guys are the best.  I just used it to export my table to a csv. I modified an entire column of about 25000 records, then imported it back into the original table.  Try it on your test db and see if it works for you.

Best of Luck
MKW